# Метод isChangingConfigurations()

Tags: android, activity

В  документации сказано, что метод isChangingConfigurations() в основном используется в onStop().  Но возможно ли применение данного метода в onCreate()?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations()) - нет.

> Check to see whether this activity is in the process of being
>   **destroyed** in order to be recreated with a new configuration

Только в процессе уничтожения. `onCreate()` к процессу уничтожения точно не относится